# Tornado: transforms = [t(request) for t in self.transforms]

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I'm a python+tornado newbie so kindly bear with me.

I'm trying to develop a tornado based web application. I'm able to start the server successfully. However, when I try to access the application using browser, I get the following exception stacktrace as shown below. Any help is welcome.

```
[E 140412 18:36:43 iostream:357] Uncaught exception, closing connection.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 354, in wrapper
        callback(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
        raise_exc_info(exc)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 328, in _on_headers
        self.request_callback(self._request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1639, in __call__
        transforms = [t(request) for t in self.transforms]
    AttributeError: 'NAP' object has no attribute 'transforms'
[E 140412 18:36:43 ioloop:491] Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x1400d08>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 477, in _run_callback
        callback()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
        raise_exc_info(exc)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 354, in wrapper
        callback(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
        raise_exc_info(exc)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 328, in _on_headers
        self.request_callback(self._request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1639, in __call__
        transforms = [t(request) for t in self.transforms]
    AttributeError: 'NAP' object has no attribute 'transforms'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you subclass Application and override `__init__` without calling the superclass version?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've both for my handler

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what's going on then.  The transforms attribute is managed by the superclass, so as long as you're subclassing it correctly I don't see how you'd get this problem.